# UISwitch is not invoking the function when added with tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiswitch

I have added a switch along with each cell in table view but the switch function is not get called. If I give the switch in the front page its displaying successfully. But in tableview cell its not working   `

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].Address
    cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].Number
    cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].Role
    cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].Name
    
    //switch
    
    let mySwitch = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
    mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    mySwitch.tintColor = UIColor.red
    mySwitch.onTintColor = UIColor.green
    mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

    return cell
}

@IBAction func switchValueDidChange(_sender: UISwitch){

    if _sender .isOn{
        print("switch on")
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red         }
    else{
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemPurple
    }
}
`
```

Comment: in your code example up above, it's not clear what `view` you're trying to change the backgroundColor of.... the cell or the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature is wrong. There must be a space character between the underscore and `sender`. And if it's not a real IBAction replace `@IBAction` with `@objc`

```
@objc func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {...
```

and – not related to the issue – the selector can be simply written

```
#selector(switchValueDidChange)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked  mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector (switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)

Comment: can u say how do i change another viewcontrollers color with the same switch.  I mean if its a notes app when i click to expand the table view cell and switch pressed then the details page color have to change

Comment: That's another question and depends on the relationship between the current and *another viewcontroller*.

Comment: As I said please ask a new question and describe the relationship between the two controllers.

Comment: I have added question can u suggest answer

Comment: Again this depends on the ***relationship between the two controllers*** which is unclear. Popular patterns are callback closure, protocol/delegate, Notification and as of late publish/subscription.

Comment: 0


In such a way that in my table view cells each cell have switch. when I press one cell its showing the details in another view controller(displayViewController). i have to design such a way that when I press a switch in table view cell the switchaction have to be perfomed in displayViewController. if u give ur mail  or any id i will share code